# Efficient methods for finding a graph path with maximal total edge weight

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a weight graph, as generated by this code:

```
weightGraph=Graph[{SparseArray[Automatic, {55, 55}, 
   0, {1, {{0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 12, 15, 17, 20, 23, 26, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40,
       42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 59, 62, 65, 68, 71, 74, 77, 79, 82, 85,
       88, 91, 94, 97, 100, 102, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117, 120, 123, 
      126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 
      126}, {{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {7}, {8}, 
{9}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {12}, {13}, {14}, 
{13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {17}, {18}, {19}, 
{18}, {19}, {20}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {22}, {23}, {24}, 
{23}, {24}, {25}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {25}, {26}, {27}, {26}, {27}, 
{28}, {29}, {30}, {29}, {30}, {31}, {30}, {31}, {32}, {31}, {32}, 
{33}, {32}, {33}, {34}, {33}, {34}, {35}, {34}, {35}, {36}, {37}, 
{38}, {37}, {38}, {39}, {38}, {39}, {40}, {39}, {40}, {41}, {40}, 
{41}, {42}, {41}, {42}, {43}, {42}, {43}, {44}, {43}, {44}, {45}, 
{46}, {47}, {46}, {47}, {48}, {47}, {48}, {49}, {48}, {49}, {50}, 
{49}, {50}, {51}, {50}, {51}, {52}, {51}, {52}, {53}, {52}, {53}, 
{54}, {53}, {54}, {55}}}, Pattern}], 
  Null}, {EdgeWeight -> {79, 77, 59, 77, 57, 75, 109, 60, 72, 78, 90, 
    87, 124, 121, 149, 97, 112, 109, 124, 64, 121, 61, 146, 89, 174, 
    152, 139, 128, 154, 143, 120, 83, 60, 105, 145, 190, 99, 168, 77, 
    105, 93, 88, 82, 77, 114, 54, 91, 94, 136, 139, 173, 48, 82, 77, 
    110, 105, 107, 62, 104, 57, 99, 77, 136, 114, 41, 117, 44, 130, 
    78, 164, 101, 159, 96, 133, 98, 135, 127, 110, 78, 152, 120, 151, 
    98, 129, 115, 56, 42, 54, 128, 140, 89, 77, 26, 111, 63, 148, 136,
     140, 128, 130, 126, 87, 94, 55, 55, 86, 86, 143, 72, 129, 111, 
    141, 123, 101, 72, 50, 68, 135, 153, 185, 141, 173, 129, 175, 131,
     123}, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 10}, {0, 9}, {1, 9}, {0, 8}, {1, 
     8}, {2, 8}, {0, 7}, {1, 7}, {2, 7}, {3, 7}, {0, 6}, {1, 6}, {2, 
     6}, {3, 6}, {4, 6}, {0, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 
     5}, {0, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {0, 
     3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 3}, {7, 3}, {0, 
     2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {7, 2}, {8, 
     2}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}, {7, 
     1}, {8, 1}, {9, 1}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to find a path with maximal total edge weight from *source vertex* to *sink vertex*.  This is current the brute-force method based on `FindPath`

```
path = MaximalBy[
  Catenate[FindPath[weightGraph, 
      First[GraphComputation`SourceVertexList[weightGraph]], #, 
      Infinity, All] & /@ 
    GraphComputation`SinkVertexList[weightGraph]], 
  Total[PropertyValue[{weightGraph, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
     EdgeList[PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True]]] &]
```

> `{{35$374,42$376,67$379,82$383,92$387,98$392,75$399,89$406,51$414,90$422}}`

Show the path

```
HighlightGraph[weightGraph, PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  Thread[EdgeList[
     PathGraph[#, 
      DirectedEdges -> 
       True]] -> (PropertyValue[{weightGraph, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
      EdgeList[PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True]])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the maximal path cost is

```
Total[PropertyValue[{weightGraph, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
  EdgeList[PathGraph[First[path], DirectedEdges -> True]]]
```

> 1317

Any higher efficient method can do this but not brute force?

Comment: I think some of the shortest path finding methods work with negative weights in acyclic graphs.  Have you tried them?

Comment: What is a *violent* method?

Comment: Why do you think this algorithm isn't efficient?

Comment: @David Well, it's brute forcing it. Find *all* paths, select the longest ones. I think yode might mean "brute force" when he says "violent", perhaps a literal translation from Chinese.   There are some problems where the brute force is the best one can do.  Maybe this is one of those problems.  But more often this is not the case.

Comment: Well of course *A-star* is the provably optimal path-finding algorithm applicable to such problems.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm in check your method based on `FindShortestPath`,wait a moment.and you are right,I mean `"brute force"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make all weights negative and find shortest paths. I believe this will work with the `"BellmanFord"` method of [`FindShortestPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestPath.html) when the graph has no cycles.

This function maps `fun` onto the edge weight vector:

```
ClearAll[weightMap];
weightMap[fun_, g_ /; PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight] =!= Automatic] := 
 Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g], 
  EdgeWeight -> fun /@ PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight], 
  FilterRules[Options[g], Except[EdgeWeight]]]
```

Gets sources and sinks with documented functions:

```
sinks = 
 Pick[VertexList[weightGraph], VertexOutDegree[weightGraph], 0]
(* {46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55} *)

sources = 
 Pick[VertexList[weightGraph], VertexInDegree[weightGraph], 0]
(* {1} *)
```

There's only one source, `1`.  `FindShortestPath` will select the right method with negative weights:

```
spf = FindShortestPath[weightMap[Minus, weightGraph], 1, All]

paths = spf /@ sinks
(* {{1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 19, 24, 30, 37, 46}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 
  19, 24, 30, 37, 47}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 19, 26, 33, 40, 48}, {1, 3, 
  6, 10, 14, 19, 26, 33, 41, 49}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 19, 26, 33, 41, 
  50}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 19, 26, 33, 41, 51}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 19, 
  26, 34, 43, 52}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 19, 26, 34, 43, 53}, {1, 3, 6, 
  10, 15, 21, 28, 35, 44, 54}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}} *)

HighlightGraph[weightGraph, PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True]] & /@ 
  paths // Multicolumn
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I do forget the `FindShortestPath` can serve the negtive weight,I have tried `FindMinimumCostFlow` many many times.As [this documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeCost.html),`FindMinimumCostFlow` can work in negtive edge cost.But as my test,it not work.I don't sure it is a bug or not..